# Regular expression match an email with specific length, start, end characters

Tags: regex, email, expression

Hello I'm looking for an regular expression that match the follow condition, I tried so many expression but none of them work:

- specific email type: gmail.com
- start with a specific chacracter, for example : a
- end with a specific chacracter, for example : x
- email length 10 , for example: anemailxxx

So this one will match: anemailxxx@gmail.com

Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: what did you try and regex is needed for which language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made it yourself pretty easy to be honest, since most of the data is fixed. Basically anything that will match `a????????x@gmail.com`. There are 8 question marks since 2 characters of the 10 specified length are already fixed (the start and end)

Now to translate that into a regex:

`a(.{8})x@gmail\.com`

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked when I test with normal text. But I want to search my google drive, too much files, and it does not work :(